# Woo Subscription & Membership

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

I have 3 subscriptions connected to woo memberships. Silver,gold,platinum.

When ever anyone upgrade or downgrade the plan, I want the current membership to remain active while the upgraded membership should remain on hold until the next billing date.

Using switch settings, the payment is due on the next billing date but the current membership gets canceled and new upgraded membership gets active.

Please help me..